# Multiplying a Vector with a Tensor in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dot-product

I‘m trying to optimize some code with a numpy. Currently I have the following code:

```
for i in range(0,bodies):
    delta_y = b@(k[:,i,:])
    delta_y *= dx
    y[i] += delta_y
return y
```

where b is has the shape (5,) and k has the shape (5,3,4) is there a way to use a numpy multiplication instead of the for loop?
I already tried plenty of thing and couldn’t solve the issue.

Currently I‘m trying:

```
B = np.repeat([b], y.shape[0], axis = 0)
delta_y= B.T@k
delta_y*= dx
y = delta_y
```

And getting an (5,5,4) shape instead of a (4,) shape.

Comment: Read the `np.matmul` docs.  The first of 3 dimensions is the "batch" one, your `3`.  So a `b@k.transpose(1,0,2)` would use a (5,) and (3,5,4) to produce (3,4).  `np.einsum` can also be used, giving more control over how dimensions are paired.

Comment: For a full tested answer provide us with samples of all arrays, b, k, dx, y.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got a solution thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution, thanks to hpaulj:

```
delta_y = np.matmul(b,k.transpose(1,0,2))*dx
y += delta_y
return y
```